# Datepicker in twitterbootstrap 3 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, datepicker

I am not able to get the datepicker to work. this is a second page in the application and loads the header.jsp which has the navigation bar.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" />"></script>


<jsp:useBean id="patient" class="com.mycompany.model.Patient" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="patient" property="*"/>

<form class="navbar-form pull-left" method="POST" action="/myapp/success">
<div><table>
  <tr><td>Patient ID </td><td> <input name ="pid" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;" required></td></tr>
  <tr><td>First Name </td><td><input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Last Name </td><td><input name="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Age </td><td><input name="age" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button></td></tr>
</table></div>    
</form>


<div>
        <div class='well'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker6'/>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker6').datepicker();
            });
        </script>
</div>
```

please tell me where i am going wrong... the jquery doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: Try to find the error in browser console

Comment: there is nothing in the browser console. I think jquery is not getting loaded. but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I got it to work. the java script was at the wronr location. I moved the datepicker.js under src/main/webapp/resources/js and it worked.